# Set custom user property to retrievable

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-profile-property

As a SharePoint Online 2013 Administrator I cannot set newly created user properties to 'Retrievable' in order to make them searchable in the search center. The option is always greyed out. I can overwrite existing properties but isn't there another way to do so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Tenant Admin you can create new managed properties in Search to Retrievable for String and Yes/No data types. You do this in the Search Service Application under Search Schema. For other data types like Date and Decimal you have to reassign one of the preconfigured RefinableDATA## fields (RefinableDate01, RefinableDecimal02, etc.) I do this all the time for my sessions on search.

Two tips, since you mention this is a user property (I suspect you mean it is coming from the User Profile Service):

1. Change the Advanced Searchable Setting to PeopleIdx, this will
   associate it with People rather than SharePoint results.
2. Create/Change the property in the SSA, People property assignments
   (like BCS) don't work at the Site Collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Matthew!
Although being tenant admin I could not select the Retrievable option. I tried as you mentioned and mapped RefinableString01 with the crawled properties (lets say ows_department and PeopleDepartment). There is a Department term set that I use in a custom user property (in People) that I created. However, after mapping (in >search,>Manage Search Schema) as described above I can still not query the properties from my profile in the search. I seem to miss one link... but can't fathom what would be missing.

Comment: A full crawl has to run before you can use the property. For profiles that should happen once a day. Try changing the data to cause the indexer to reminded a person.